# How many possibilities to get to N spaces away from starting point by rolling 6-faced dice?

Tags: python, algorithm

I just started python like a week ago and now I am stuck at the question about rolling dice. This is a question that my friend sent to me yesterday and I have just no idea how to solve it myself.

> Imagine you are playing a board game. You roll a 6-faced dice and move forward the same number of spaces that you rolled. If the finishing point is “n” spaces away from the starting point, please implement a program that calculates how many possible ways there are to arrive exactly at the finishing point.

So it seems I shall make a function with a parameter with "N" and when it reaches a certain point, let's say 10, so we all can see how many possibilities there are to get to 10 spaces away from the starting point.

I suppose this is something to do with "compositions" but I am not sure how it should be coded in python.

Please, python masters!

Comment: what have you tried? post some code

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? Don't think about what kind of data structure you would use. Figure out the solution in your mind first.

Comment: Your problem must have 2 params, the number you must add N and the number of times you roll the dice M, right? The question needs much more clarity

Comment: Do you have a mathematical solution to your problem and are struggling with the implementation? If not, this is not the right forum

Comment: The question doesn't specify anything at all. I mean, neither data structure I could choose or how many parameters are required. It seems there is only one parameter N which indicates how many steps away from starting point.

Comment: This is the mathematical solution that I am thinking to implement in python: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1895119/how-many-ways-to-reach-nth-number-from-starting-point-using-any-number-steps-b However, I am too new in python to make this work :(

Comment: Do you know about recursion?

Comment: It will be only for your harm if someone provides the exact code to the problem whose concept and solution you already know but cant convert to python code. Would recommend to learn basics of python , then try and then ask if you have problem in your code. Other wise you will never be able to learn.

Comment: Thanks MBo! You talk about recursion and it was such a biggest help to make this code work! I made it guys! Thanks for your help python masters!

Answer (score 9):

This is one way to compute the result that is exact, and uses neither iteration nor recursion:

```
def ways(n):
    A = 3**(n+6)
    M = A**6 - A**5 - A**4 - A**3 - A**2 - A - 1
    return pow(A, n+6, M) % A

for i in xrange(20):
    print i, '->', ways(i)
```

The output is in agreement with https://oeis.org/A001592

```
0 -> 1
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3 -> 4
4 -> 8
5 -> 16
6 -> 32
7 -> 63
8 -> 125
9 -> 248
10 -> 492
11 -> 976
12 -> 1936
13 -> 3840
14 -> 7617
15 -> 15109
16 -> 29970
17 -> 59448
18 -> 117920
19 -> 233904
```

Comment: You are the only one who wrote an actual code for this question, and I am really grateful! Although, I wrote a code in a recursive way, your code looks neat, except your code might work too slow to execute a big number when it actually comes to an action.

Comment: @Paul Hankin This code exploits unusual math trick. Is it some consequence  of well-known matrix powering? Would you give some explanation or link?

Comment: It's neither well-known, nor matrix-related. There's similar examples for Fibonacci on http://fare.tunes.org/files/fun/fibonacci.lisp and my own blog https://paulhankin.github.io/Fibonacci/ but I think the application to generalized Fibonacci sequences is original. Note the example on my blog is not efficient because it uses vastly long ints, but the answer here _is_ efficient (as is a similar example on the fare.tunes.org blog).

Comment: A less tricksy way to write this program is to compute X^n in the polynomial ring Z[X]/(X^6-X^5-X^4-X^3-X^2-X-1). Essentially that's what the code in the answer does, but with the abstract "X" replaced by a large number "A".

Comment: @Paul Hankin Thanks. Quite complex algebra is involved :)

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of calculation I found a solution that it creates a Hexanacci series. Now let me explain Hexanacci series a little bit. In the Hexanacci series each element is the summation of previous 6 elements. So I achieved this in Objective-C by just using a for loop which can be easily convert to any language:

```
-(void)getPossibleWaysFor:(NSInteger)number
 {
  static unsigned long ways;

  unsigned long first = 0;
  unsigned long second = 0;
  unsigned long third = 0;
  unsigned long fourth = 0;
  unsigned long fifth = 0;
  unsigned long sixth = 1;

  for (int i = 0; i<= number; i++) {

    ways = first + second + third + fourth + fifth + sixth;

    if (i>0) {
        first = second;
        second = third;
        third = fourth;
        fourth = fifth;
        fifth = sixth;
        sixth = ways;
    }

    NSLog(@"%d : -> %ld",i,ways);
}
return ways;}
```

// Result:

```
[self getPossibleWaysFor:20];

0 : -> 1
1 : -> 1
2 : -> 2
3 : -> 4
4 : -> 8
5 : -> 16
6 : -> 32
7 : -> 63
8 : -> 125
9 : -> 248
10 : -> 492
11 : -> 976
12 : -> 1936
13 : -> 3840
14 : -> 7617
15 : -> 15109
16 : -> 29970
17 : -> 59448
18 : -> 117920
19 : -> 233904
20 : -> 463968
```

Answer (score 2):

Im not really good in python but I can help you using ruby ;)

```
def ways(n)
  return ways(n-1) + ways(n-2) + ways(n-3) + ways(n-4) + ways(n-5) + ways(n-6) if n >= 6
  return ways(4) + ways(3) + ways(2) + ways(1) + ways(0) if n == 5
  return ways(3) + ways(2) + ways(1) + ways(0) if n == 4
  return ways(2) + ways(1) + ways(0) if n == 3
  return ways(1) + ways(0) if n == 2
  return ways(0) if n == 1
  return 1 if n == 0
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i'm not expert in python but Java can solve this, you can easily transform it to language you want :

**First idea using recursion :**

The idea is to create all possible combinaisons in a GameTree after calculate the sum requested and increment out counter.

```
public class GameTree {
public int value;
public GameTree[] childs;

public GameTree(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public GameTree(int value, GameTree[] childs) {
    this.value = value;
    this.childs = childs;
}
```

}

For Memory issue i'll ignore the subtree superior to our sum ([Like Alpha–beta pruning algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning))

```
    static void generateGameTreeRecursive(String path, GameTree node, int winnerScore, int currentScore) throws InterruptedException {

    // Build the path
    if(node.value != 0)// We exclude the root node
        path += " " + String.valueOf(node.value);

    if (winnerScore <= currentScore) {
        // lierate the current node (prevent for Java heap space error)
        node = null;
        // Add the winner route
        count++;
        // Finish for this node
        return;
    } else{
        // cerate the childs
        node.childs = new GameTree[6];
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            // Generate the possible values to the childs
            node.childs[i] = new GameTree(i+1);             
            // Recursion for each child
            generateGameTreeRecursive(path, node.childs[i], winnerScore, currentScore + i + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Second idea using iteration :**

This solution is more elegant just dont ask me how i found it :)

```
// Returns number of ways to reach score n
static int getCombinaison(int n)
{
    int[] table = new int[n+1];
    // table[i] will store count of solutions for

    // Base case (If given value is 0)
    table[0] = 1;

    // One by one consider given 3 moves and update the table[]
    // values after the index greater than or equal to the
    // value of the picked move
    for (int j=1; j<7; j++) {
        for (int i=j; i<=n; i++)
           table[i] += table[i-j];
    }

    return table[n];
}
```

Comment: How you found it? The second Idea?